# Nested JSON Request with Volley -> Escaped chars

Tags: java, encoding, escaping, gson, android-volley

I want to make a post request with volley to a REST API.
Therefore, I create a JSONObject and put a JSON String generated from a class in it.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
String json = gson.toJson(MyClazz);
try {
    jsonObject.put(PARAM,  json);
}
catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that the correct calculated JSON String gets escaped and can't be recognized on the back end.

So `toJson()` gives something like:

```
{
    "device_identifier":"324234234",
    "name":"NameMe",
    "list":[
        {"prop":"A","prop2":-10},
        {"prop":"B","prop2":-12}
    ]
}
```

The jsonObject's output is like

```
{
    "PARAM":{
        \"device_identifier\":\"324234234\",
        \"name\":\"NameMe\",
        \"list\":[
            {\"prop\":\"A\",\"prop2\":-10},
            {\"prop\":\"B\","\prop2\":-12}
        ]
    }
}
```

I need the PARAM for the JSON structure so I can't give it directly to the REST-API. Any ideas how I can avoid the additional escaping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your `MyClazz` object with a simple wrapper object, and then pass that wrapped object to Gson's `toJson` method.

Given this class based on your example JSON,

```
public class MyClazz {
    public String device_identifier;
    public String name;
    public List<Prop> list;
    public class Prop {
        public String prop;
        public Integer prop2;
    }
}
```

here's a possible wrapper implementation.  Note the use of `com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName` which tells Gson to use the `PARAM` key in the JSON representation.

```
public class MyClazzWrapper {
    public MyClazzWrapper(MyClazz myClazz) {
        this.myClazz = myClazz;
    }
    @SerializedName("PARAM")
    private MyClazz myClazz;
}
```

And here's an example using it:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

MyClazz myClazz = gson.fromJson("{\"device_identifier\":\"324234234\",\"name\":\"NameMe\",\"list\":[{\"prop\":\"A\",\"prop2\":-10},{\"prop\":\"B\",\"prop2\":-12}]}", MyClazz.class);
MyClazzWrapper wrapped = new MyClazzWrapper(myClazz);

System.out.println(gson.toJson(wrapped));
```

The above will print:

```
{
    "PARAM": {
        "device_identifier": "324234234",
        "name": "NameMe",
        "list": [
            {
                "prop": "A",
                "prop2": -10
            },
            {
                "prop": "B",
                "prop2": -12
            }
        ]
    }
}
```